# split a series in pandas pipe separated (with equal sign) into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I'm relatively new to Python and would like to seek your help in the following problem. My current series of information looks like this:

```
df['word_feats']
------------------------------------------------
0                                                   Case=Loc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
1                                                   Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
2                                                                              PunctType=Comm
3                                                   Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
4                                                   Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
5                                                                                        None
6                                                   Case=Nom|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
7                                                   Case=Loc|Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
8                                                            Gender=Neut|Number=Sing|Person=3
9                                                   Case=Loc|Gender=Neut|Number=Plur|Person=3
10                                                                                       None
```

My results in a single column are not in a dictionary format (which would be easier). Instead, it is in a pipe separated format with equals sign.

I am hoping to split this series into multiple columns, taking the 'key' (in this case, LEFT of equal sign) as the column name, and 'value' (RIGHT of equal sign) as my cell.

I've tried something along this line:

```
df['word_feats'].str.split('|', expand=True)
```

Which doesn't work as:

1. It doesn't take the 'key' as column name
2. My values are in the wrong columns!

Would appreciate any answers for this! Thanks.

Comment: How do you build your pandas df? What's the source of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a regular expression pattern to find all the occurrences of key-value pairs from each row, this will generate a list of tuples in every row, then map each list to `dict` and construct a dataframe from the mapped records

```
pd.DataFrame(map(dict, df['word_feats'].str.findall(r'([^|=]+)=([^|]+)')))
```

---

```
   Case Gender Number Person PunctType
0   Loc   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
1   Nom   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
2   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN      Comm
3   Nom   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
4   Nom   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
5   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
6   Nom   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
7   Loc   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
8   NaN   Neut   Sing      3       NaN
9   Loc   Neut   Plur      3       NaN
10  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I have overcome this issue by doing the following:

Step 1: Convert series to dictionary:

```
word_feats_dict=[]
for i in df['word_feats']:
    
    if i== None:
        q='None'
    else: 
        q = dict(item.split('=') for item in i.split('|'))
    
    word_feats_dict.append(q)

df['word_feats_dict']=word_feats_dict              # creating another series that is in dictionary form.
```

Step 2: Explode dictionary into Multiple columns

```
df['word_feats_dict'].apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df.drop(['word_feats_dict'],axis=1),df['word_feats_dict'].apply(pd.Series)],axis=1)
df.drop(columns=0,inplace=True)    # As I have 'None' as some of my values, they turned out to be a column on itself called '0'.
```